# Using IMAP() in Php get mails since specific datetime

Tags: php, imap

We are running one script for every 5 minutes,When script runs we are storing that time into db(last_run_time),
when next time script runs we want to get the mails from that time(Since last_run_time)

Comment: IMAP is implemented or used in a library?

Comment: used as library

Comment: From IMAP specification, there is a SEARCH command. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-6.4.4  So the library shall have this kind of function. Otherwise, you will have to implement it yourself or use another library.

Comment: The SEARCH command only supports day granularity.  You should be storing the highest UID you processed, as these are assigned increasing.